# Простите, но опять падежи

Tags: падежи

Победители - вот кем они были! 
"Победителями" - не смотрится. Или удачнее будет: "Победители - вот кто это был!" Но тоже режет глаза. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форма вполне допустима.
"Кто были" - это другое. Ответ подразумевает личность (Иванов, Петров, Сидоров)
"Кем были" - пехотинцами, десантниками, моряками...

Возможно Ваше "не смотрится" связано с этим.

Answer (score 2):

Победители - вот КТО они были! Победителями - вот кем были они!

Рассогласование падежей, тут по-моему, фразу не красит.

Comment: Здесь нет рассогласования. Вы смысла, имхо, не поняли.

Answer (score 1):

**Победители - вот кем они были!**  Вполне допустимо, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 0):

А почему, собственно, были? Они остаются победителями. Особенно если имеются в виду участники Великой Отечественной.